# Whats wrong with this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT STOCK_SYMBOL FROM daily
WHERE DAILY_DATE > '2011-03-01 23:59:59'
GROUP BY STOCK_SYMBOL HAVING MAX(DAILY_CHANGE_PERCENT) < -0.1
```

This is my structure:

```
STOCK_ID    STOCK_SYMBOL    DAILY_DATE            DAILY_CHANGE_PERCENT
1           GOOG            2011-03-03 01:01:01   -0.300
```

I'm trying to get only the stocks that for every date within that date range, `DAILY_CHANGE_PERCENT` is lower than -0.1

at the moment i'm getting mixed results.

**Example of a valid result:**

```
STOCK_ID    STOCK_SYMBOL    DAILY_DATE            DAILY_CHANGE_PERCENT
1           GOOG            2011-03-03 01:01:01   -0.300
1           GOOG            2011-03-04 01:01:01   -0.110
1           GOOG            2011-03-05 01:01:01   -0.500
1           GOOG            2011-03-06 01:01:01   -0.200
```

Thanks,

Comment: What's the result you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: @BoltClock I'm trying to get only the stocks that are in constant price drop since 2011-03-01 23:59:59 of over -0.1 percent.

at the moment i'm getting mixed results.

Comment: What is the problem with your query ? What is the error ? Can you give a bigger data set and some results your having

Comment: @Krtek there is no error, but i'm not getting what i'm expecting to get.. When I look at the results I see stocks that have positive ``DAILY_CHANGE_PERCENT`` within the time period of ``> 2011-03-01 23:59:59``

Comment: What is "constant price drop"?  Stock price has been declining EVERY day since the starting day?  Not sure what you mean by "constant". Your query does not eliminate stocks whose price is fluctuating up/down.

Comment: @Tim - looking for stocks within that date range that for every row the ``DAILY_CHANGE_PERCENT`` is lower than -0.1

Comment: How did you get the output if you have GROUP BY STOCK_SYMBOL. You have multiple STOCK_SYMBOL in the valid result section.

Comment: @Pentium10 - in the example of valid result I gave? I didn't get that output, I just wanted everyone to better understand what i'm looking for, I would only get 'GOOG', not the whole data set and it will only be mentioned once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your `"valid result"` with all columns, is this what you used?

```
SELECT daily.STOCK_ID, STOCK_SYMBOL, DAILY_DATE, DAILY_CHANGE_PERCENT
FROM daily
join (
    SELECT STOCK_ID
    FROM daily
    WHERE DAILY_DATE > '2011-03-01 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY STOCK_ID
    HAVING MAX(DAILY_CHANGE_PERCENT) < -0.1
) X ON X.STOCK_ID = daily.STOCK_ID
WHERE DAILY_DATE > '2011-03-01 23:59:59'
```

I swapped to stock_id in case there are duplicate symbols.
Notice also that I use the date filter twice.

Answer (score 0):

You want the distinct set of stock symbols where there is any drop in price duing the specified period AND you want to remove from that set of stock symbols any stock whose price went up on any day in the specified period.  Simply looking for a maximum drop of less than 'x' does not rule out stocks that may have gone up at some point.

Comment: Yes. So basically all ``STOCK_SYMBOL`` within the date range that the ``DAILY_CHANGE_PERCENT``is lower than -0.1 (for any date within the date range). if there is a positive value for example during that date range it should not display the stock symbol

Comment: Yes, but since you're working with daily rows,the same symbol will appear more than once, so you will need to extract the distinct set of stock symbols that meet your criterion of "dropped in price during period" and then remove from that set any symbol where price went up in period. You want all stock symbols where EVERY one of its daily rows in period reflects a drop in price.

Comment: That's true, how do I do that?

Comment: Check out " not exists ( select ... ) " syntax and read up on "inline views".

Comment: If you add the max(daily_change_percent) to your column-list what happens? SELECT STOCK_SYMBOL, max(daily_change_percent)...

Answer (score 0):

What data type you have of `DAILY_CHANGE_PERCENT` column?
if this is `varchar` or so the lower-than won't work.

Otherwise - I look at your query and it seems to be OK.

**UPDATE**

Or try this one:

```
SELECT STOCK_SYMBOL 
FROM daily
GROUP BY STOCK_SYMBOL 
HAVING MAX(DAILY_CHANGE_PERCENT) < -0.1 AND DAILY_DATE > '2011-03-01 23:59:59'
```